# Strings-set Regex Query Like Charsets for Match Any Order

Tags: php, regex, string

Assume we have 3 strings:

```
lorem,ipsum,set
```

and code, input strings and expected results are:

```
$array = array(
    "lorem" => "lorem",
    "loremipsum" => "loremipsum",
    "loremipsumset" => "FOUND!",
    "abc loremipsumset xyz" => "abc FOUND! xyz",
    "ipsumsetlorem" => "FOUND!",
    "ipsumloremset" => "FOUND!",
    "setipsumloremsetset" => "FOUND!",
    "loremloremipsumipsumsetset" => "FOUND!", // tough one...
    "lorem ipsum set" => "lorem ipsum set",
) ;
foreach ($array as $string => $expect) {
    $result preg_replace($REGEX,'FOUND!','abacdaef');
    echo ($result == $expect ? 'THANKS!!' : '...') ;
    echo '<br>' ;
}
```

Three string have to be together in given input, but with any order...

```
"/((lorem|ipsum|set)+(lorem|ipsum|set)+(lorem|ipsum|set)+)+/"
```

This will work somehow, but it is also matching with "loremloremlorem",

What kind of Regex can handle that? or is there any simple way?

Comment: Actually, why not use just `"/(?:lorem|ipsum|set)+/"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think some of the examples that are provided imply that strings that don't contain all of the substrings shouldn't match. For example, I don't think "lorem" should match.

Comment: Yes, but the first regex is not appropriate then. It should be [`([abc])(?!\1)([abc])(?!\1|\2)[abc]`](https://regex101.com/r/fL1fR0/1). That also means it is not a good job for a regex. The second one must be [`(lorem|ipsum|set)(?!\1)(lorem|ipsum|set)(?!\1|\2)(?:lorem|ipsum|set)`](https://regex101.com/r/fL1fR0/2). That is not easily expandable in case of tens of strings.

Comment: I don't understand your loop. It's not using `$string` anywhere. Did you mean to use that as the argument to `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.
Php supports conditionals. If you put a guard around each word you want to
match, it will force the engine to match all of them at least once.

https://regex101.com/r/fL1fR0/3

To add another string:

- Put it in a separate group with its group conditional `| ((?(4)(?!))new string)`
- Add it to the overall alternation list `(?: lorem | ipsum | set | new string)`
- Increment the range to equal the number of seperate strings `{4}`

---

This matches all the places in your array where FOUND is substituted.

`\b(?:(?:((?(1)(?!))lorem)|((?(2)(?!))ipsum)|((?(3)(?!))set))(?:lorem|ipsum|set)*){3}\b`

Expanded

```
 \b 
 (?:
      (?:
           (                        # (1)
                (?(1)
                     (?!)
                )
                lorem
           )
        |  (                        # (2)
                (?(2)
                     (?!)
                )
                ipsum
           )
        |  (                        # (3)
                (?(3)
                     (?!)
                )
                set
           )
      )
      (?: lorem | ipsum | set )*
 ){3}
 \b
```

Comment: /((lorem|ipsum|set)+(lorem|ipsum|set)+(lorem|ipsum|set)+)/ works better

Comment: Better? Can you explain better.

Comment: If this https://regex101.com/r/wW2cG6/1 is your outcome then just `(lorem|ipsum|set){3,}`  is all you need because they are identical.

Comment: The regex I posted validates 3 unique items exist in the string. If I read you wrong, sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah, like I said it matches `setsetset` same as `(lorem|ipsum|set){3,}` would.

Comment: (lorem|ipsum|set){3,} quite near, but "loremloremlorem" will also match... http://ideone.com/2sM8bh

Comment: Thank you for your time!! But it is a problem that never considered on Regex syntax design I think :)

Comment: I've said `(?:lorem|ipsum|set)+(?:lorem|ipsum|set)+(?:lorem|ipsum|set)+` is _identical_ to `(?:lorem|ipsum|set){3,}` with respect to matching the same string's. It's ludicrous to think that capturing 3 groups will get you anything of use. Primarily because they are quantified.

Comment: They are not identical: its a strings chain. you would write if it was (?:lorem|ipsum|set)+|(?:lorem|ipsum|set)+|(?:lorem|ipsum|set)+ "|", the or char, then it would be identical with (?:lorem|ipsum|set){3,} somehow

Comment: Yes, but regex _string chains_ can be factored out. Consider a math analogy: if `A = (?:lorem|ipsum|set)` then your regex is `A+A+A+` Since _A is required at least three times_, that factors out to be `A{3,}` Therefore, they _are_ identical in every way!

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean now: My regex is matching "loremloremlorem" as well...But your suggested regex is quite complex, think of it is for 10 strings... And those parenthises are ruining my output matching...

Comment: and my first charset regex ([abc]+) introduction is also failing when it is "aaa bbb ccc"... Thank you for your time again!

Comment: Well, the technique I posted is linear, 1 for 1. There are no permutations at all. So, you can force as many unique strings to exist as your engine has capture buffers. If you have 100 strings, use 100 capture groups, just copy/paste new items.

Comment: Thank you I will consider your regex again :) it seems it is only choise :)

Comment: There are other variations to this technique that can be very complex. This is just a basic template. If you can understand this it will open the door to many things. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! But your regex is also matching with "lorem ipsum set", the spaces... Anyway :)

Comment: You would have to show me, there is no spaces in my regex. If you're using the _expanded_ regex, you need to tell the engine it's expanded with the `/../x` modifier. Most likely you let in a stray space in the compressed regex.